# How to read all mail include specific subject from outlook in c#

Tags: c#, outlook

In my outlook I have a lot of e-mail and some of them's subjects are same; `document from program`
What I want is I have to find all of them. But in my code it only find only one.How can I fix it.

```
  try
    {
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application MyApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace MailNS = MyApp.GetNamespace("mapi");
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder MyInbox = null;
     MyInbox = MailNS.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem InboxMailItem = null;
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items oItems = MyInbox.Items;

     string Query = "[Subject] = 'document from program'";
     InboxMailItem = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem)oItems.Find(Query);

     Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}", InboxMailItem.Subject);
     Console.WriteLine("Sendername: {0}", InboxMailItem.SenderName);
     Console.WriteLine("Body: {0}", InboxMailItem.Body);
    }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
     MessageBox.Show("There is no mail with that subject");
     }
```

Sorry for my english

Answer (score -1):

It looks like Find() returns "**an** Outlook item object that satisfies the given Filter"

Note "an" which is singular - so - the first match

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.items?view=outlook-pia

From there I think you need to iteratively call FindNext() to get all the items

> ```
> > FindNext() After the Find(String) method runs, this method finds and 
> > returns the next Outlook item in the specified collection.
> ```